# My mom having a surgery, wants cat out

Tags: cats, surgery

My mom will have a surgery in a couple of weeks, and has been telling me that I have to take my cat out of the house (probably some uncle can take care of it). I wonder if there is any scientific background on why it is bad to have a pet when one is recovering from surgery.

If this is not the case, could you provide some articles about this issue so that I can convince my mom to keep the cat?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What exactly about having the cat worries her? Also, how difficult is the recovery expected to be?

Comment: it might be helpful to know a little more about the age of the cat and about how long your mother have had the cat,is it an outdoor cat or indoor only.the risk might change a lot if one have a tiny young rocket powered furball versus an 15 years old couch potato of a cat.

Comment: Not really an answer but it sounds like your mom never liked the cat and this is a good excuse as any to send it away. Sorry to sound cruel but don't expect to get the cat back even after she recovers.

Comment: @Kai she wouldn't explain that to me. the recovery should be about 2 weeks, she's getting her ovaries extirpated

Comment: @trondhansen the cat is a 1.5 year old cat, we've had it for a year. We allow it to go to our backyard, and he climbs a couple of trees and visits other houses.

Comment: @VladimirVargas thank you for this information,it might be easier to get an answer about the risk for your mother when this is known.

Answer (score 7):

Most of this is going to come from what I remember from a University assignment a decade ago.

There is scientific evidence suggests that a cats purr can aid healing. A cat’s purr frequency is between 25 & 150 Hertz. *google* the low end is a similar frequency to the one that medical professionals use in vibrational therapies to promote tissue regeneration.

Known benefits of a cat purring

*Lowering stress — petting a purring cat can calm you

*A cat’s purr can decrease the symptoms of dyspnoea (difficulty breathing) in both cats and humans

*Lower blood pressure by interacting with the cat and hearing the purring sound

*Reducing the risk of heart disease (cat owners have 40% less risk of having a heart attack. Probably because of lowered BP)

*Purr vibrations help to heal infections, swelling, bone healing and growth, pain relief, muscle growth and repair, tendon repair and joint mobility

Comment: This doesn't address why the mother would want the cat _out_.